# Haskell binary search tree with custom data

Tags: haskell, tree

I want to create a binary search tree of custom data type Book. Book has two attributes, name and page. I want to use attribute page as the node of the tree. I've stuck at defining the tree. Can anyone help me with any resource? Here is the code I've tried (it's not working)

```
import System.IO  
import Data.List  

data Book = Book{
    name:: String,
    page::Int
}deriving (Show)

data Tree a = EmptyTree | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

singleton :: (Book _ x) -> Tree x   
singleton (Book _ x) = Node x EmptyTree EmptyTree  

treeInsert :: (Ord a) => a -> Tree a -> Tree a  
treeInsert (Book _ x) EmptyTree = singleton (Book _ x)
treeInsert (Book _ x) (Node a left right)   
    | x == a = Node x left right  
    | x < a  = Node a (treeInsert (Book _ x) left) right  
    | x > a  = Node a left (treeInsert (Book _ x) right)
```

Comment: How are you stuck in defining the tree? You already defined the tree.

Comment: Your types are off. `Book` does not take a type variable, and `singleton` returns a `Tree Int`.

Comment: Do you want your `Tree` to hold only `Book`s, or do you want it to hold any type?  Right now, you are somewhere in between.

Comment: @pat I want to hold books only

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to you to use all the book entity and make and `Ord` instance for `Book`.

```
instance Eq Book where
    (Book _ n1) == (Book _ n2) = n1 == n2

instance Ord Book where
    (Book _ n1) > (Book _ n2) = n1 > n2
```

And change your code to this:

```
data Book = Book {
    name :: String,
    page :: Int
} deriving (Show)

data Tree a = EmptyTree | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

singleton :: a -> Tree a   
singleton x = Node x EmptyTree EmptyTree  

treeInsert :: (Ord a) => a -> Tree a -> Tree a  
treeInsert x EmptyTree = singleton x
treeInsert x (Node a left right)   
    | x == a = Node x left right  
    | x < a  = Node a (treeInsert x left) right  
    | x > a  = Node a left (treeInsert x right)
```

You will see that `(Book _ n)` is not a correct type, `Book` is.

And a will use values of any type to `treeInsert` since `Book` implements `Ord`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if we figure out the correct type signatures.

I presume you want the `Tree` to hold `Book`s, ordered by `page`.

If we want `Tree` to hold only `Book`, we don't need to parameterize it.  However, since you did parameterize `Tree`, let's assume that it can hold more than just `Book`s.

In this case, we would expect:

```
singleton :: a -> Tree a
treeInsert :: Ord a => a -> Tree a -> Tree a
```

Where `a` could be `Book`, or any other appropriate type.  However, in order for `treeInsert`  to work with `Book`, we require `Book` to have an `Ord` instance.

The `singleton` function just puts the whole `a` into a `Node`:

```
singleton a = Node a EmptyTree EmptyTree
```

Note that `Book` does not appear in this definition since it is intended to work with all types.

The `insertTree` function will also not mention `Book`, but it will take advantage of the `Ord` instance it requires of its argument.

Edit

If you want `Tree` to work only with `Book`, then you should define it as:

```
data Tree = EmptyTree | Node Book Tree Tree
```

The type signatures for the functions then become:

```
singleton :: Book -> Tree
insertTree :: Book -> Tree -> Tree
```

The implementation of `singleton` will be the same as above (just put the whole `Book` into a `Node`).

Since `insertTree` now knows it is dealing with `Book`, it no longer requires the `Ord` instance, since it can just get the `page`.

It will start:

```
treeInsert b EmptyTree = singleton b
treeInsert b (Node a l r)
    | page b == page a = ...
```